# Ridge penalizing l2 norm of coefficients

Tags: euclidean-distance

What does this mean?:

Ridge penalizes the l2 norm of the coefficients, or the Euclidean length of w.

It is from the textbook : Introduction to Machine Learning with Python

Answer (score 0):

Ridge regression penalizes the model coefficients in order to correct for overfitting. As you have probably learned, overfitting occurs when you have too many parameters in your model which causes it to memorize the data (which leads to poor generalization). In ridge regression you add a bias to the regression estimates in order to reduce the variance. This works by adding a penalty term to the loss function in order to decrease the contribution of each feature to the model outcome. I hope this helps!